# How do I dynamically make calculations via a CASE statement based on the results of the previous row's calculations in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to make calculations via `CASE` statements which rely on the results of calculations made on the previous row. The data I'm working with is hierarchical data. My end goal is to structure the resulting data to be in line with a [Modified Preorder Tree Traversal algorithm](https://gist.github.com/tmilos/f2f999b5839e2d42d751).

Here's what my raw data looks like:

```
+-------+--------+
| id    | parent |
+-------+--------+
| 1     | (null) |
+-------+--------+
| 600   | 1      |
+-------+--------+
| 690   | 600    |
+-------+--------+
| 6990  | 690    |
+-------+--------+
| 6900  | 690    |
+-------+--------+
| 69300 | 6900   |
+-------+--------+
| 69400 | 6900   |
+-------+--------+
```

Here's what I want the end result to look like. I'm happy to expand on why this is what I'm looking for, related to MPTT, etc.

```
+-------+-----------+-----+------+--+--+--+--+
| id    | parent_id | lft | rght |  |  |  |  |
+-------+-----------+-----+------+--+--+--+--+
| 1     |           | 1   | 14   |  |  |  |  |
+-------+-----------+-----+------+--+--+--+--+
| 600   | 1         | 2   | 13   |  |  |  |  |
+-------+-----------+-----+------+--+--+--+--+
| 690   | 600       | 3   | 12   |  |  |  |  |
+-------+-----------+-----+------+--+--+--+--+
| 6900  | 690       | 4   | 9    |  |  |  |  |
+-------+-----------+-----+------+--+--+--+--+
| 6990  | 690       | 10  | 11   |  |  |  |  |
+-------+-----------+-----+------+--+--+--+--+
| 69300 | 6900      | 5   | 6    |  |  |  |  |
+-------+-----------+-----+------+--+--+--+--+
| 69400 | 6900      | 7   | 8    |  |  |  |  |
+-------+-----------+-----+------+--+--+--+--+
```

Here's what my SQL code looks like so far. It calculates many of the fields that I think the algorithm that I describe below requires. This is "organization" data within an enterprise setting, which is why the `orgn` abbreviation is common in my code.

Here's the algorithm that I think will successfully transform it into the MPTT format:

```
-If level is root (lvl=1), lft = 1, rght = subnodes*2 + 2
-If level is the next level down (lvl = prev_lvl+1), and prev_parent != parent (meaning this is the first sibling)
    -lft = parent_lft+1
-If lvl = prev_lvl, so we are on the same level (don’t know if this is a true sibling of the same parent yet)
    -if parent = prev_parent, lft=prev_rght+1 (true sibling, just use previous sibling’s right + 1)
    -if parent != prev_parent, lft=parent_lft+1 (same level, not true sibling, so use parent’s left + 1)

-rght=(subnodes*2) + lft + 1
```

SQL Code I have so far:

```
WITH tab1 (
    id,
    parent_id
) AS (
    SELECT
        1,
        NULL
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        600,
        1
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        690,
        600
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        6990,
        690
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        6900,
        690
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        69300,
        6900
    FROM
        dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        69400,
        6900
    FROM
        dual
),t1 (
    id,
    parent_id,
    lvl
) AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        parent_id,
        1 AS lvl
    FROM
        tab1
    WHERE
        parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        t2.id,
        t2.parent_id,
        lvl + 1
    FROM
        tab1 t2,
        t1
    WHERE
        t2.parent_id = t1.id
)
    SEARCH BREADTH FIRST BY id SET order1,orgn_subnodes AS (
    SELECT
        id AS id,
        COUNT(*) - 1 AS subnodes
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                CONNECT_BY_ROOT ( t1.id ) AS id
            FROM
                t1
            CONNECT BY
                PRIOR t1.id = t1.parent_id
        )
    GROUP BY
        id
),orgn_partial_data AS (
    SELECT
        orgn_subnodes.id AS id,
        orgn_subnodes.subnodes,
        parent_id,
        lvl,
        LAG(lvl,1) OVER(
            ORDER BY
                order1
        ) AS prev_lvl,
        LAG(parent_id,1) OVER(
            ORDER BY
                order1
        ) AS prev_parent,
        CASE
                WHEN parent_id IS NULL THEN 1
            END
        lft,
        CASE
                WHEN parent_id IS NULL THEN ( subnodes * 2 ) + 2
            END
        rght,
        order1
    FROM
        orgn_subnodes
        JOIN t1 ON orgn_subnodes.id = t1.id
) SELECT
    *
  FROM
    orgn_partial_data;
```

The result is:

```
+-------+----------+-----------+-----+----------+-------------+-----+------+--------+
| id    | subnodes | parent_id | lvl | prev_lvl | prev_parent | lft | rght | order1 |
+-------+----------+-----------+-----+----------+-------------+-----+------+--------+
| 1     | 6        |           | 1   |          |             | 1   | 14   | 1      |
+-------+----------+-----------+-----+----------+-------------+-----+------+--------+
| 600   | 5        | 1         | 2   | 1        |             |     |      | 2      |
+-------+----------+-----------+-----+----------+-------------+-----+------+--------+
| 690   | 4        | 600       | 3   | 2        | 1           |     |      | 3      |
+-------+----------+-----------+-----+----------+-------------+-----+------+--------+
| 6900  | 2        | 690       | 4   | 3        | 600         |     |      | 4      |
+-------+----------+-----------+-----+----------+-------------+-----+------+--------+
| 6990  | 0        | 690       | 4   | 4        | 690         |     |      | 5      |
+-------+----------+-----------+-----+----------+-------------+-----+------+--------+
| 69300 | 0        | 6900      | 5   | 4        | 690         |     |      | 6      |
+-------+----------+-----------+-----+----------+-------------+-----+------+--------+
| 69400 | 0        | 6900      | 5   | 5        | 6900        |     |      | 7      |
+-------+----------+-----------+-----+----------+-------------+-----+------+--------+
```

I don't care about the ordering of "sibling nodes" within the tree. Also, if you don't find the SQL I've started on useful, you can post an answer that doesn't use any of it. I only posted to show what pieces of info I think I need to perform the steps of the algorithm.

I'll accept any Oracle code (database procedure, SELECT statement, etc) as an answer.

Please ask for more details if you need them!

Comment: I would always write such code in a higher level language (c++, .net, java, ruby, phyton)

Comment: @RadimBača I didn't think of that! This could be a good Pandas use-case, since I'm mainly a Python dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a typo in starting post, it should be (7, 8) and not (4, 8) for 69400.

The canonical way to get the result is by using recursive procedure/function.
Below approach uses procedure and temporary table but you can achieve the same with function returning collection.

Temporary table

```
create global temporary table tmp$ (id int, l int, r int) on commit delete rows;
```

Package

```
create or replace package pkg as
  procedure p(p_id in int);
end pkg;
/
sho err
```

Package body

```
create or replace package body pkg as

  seq int;

  procedure p_(p_id in int) as
  begin
    seq := seq + 1;
    insert into tmp$(id, l, r) values (p_id, seq, null);
    for i in (select id from tab1 where parent_id = p_id order by id) loop
      p_(i.id);
    end loop;
    seq := seq + 1;    
    update tmp$ set r = seq where id = p_id;
  end;

  procedure p(p_id in int) as
  begin
    seq := 0;
    p_(p_id);
  end;  

end pkg;
/
sho err
```

Test in SQL*PLus

```
SQL> exec pkg.p(1);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from tmp$;

        ID          L          R
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1         14
       600          2         13
       690          3         12
      6900          4          9
     69300          5          6
     69400          7          8
      6990         10         11

7 rows selected.
```

**Update**

Standalone procedure without global variables

```
create or replace procedure p(p_id in int, seq in out int) as
begin
  seq := seq + 1;
  insert into tmp$(id, l, r) values (p_id, seq, null);
  for i in (select id from tab1 where parent_id = p_id order by id) loop
    p(i.id, seq);
  end loop;
  seq := seq + 1;
  update tmp$ set r = seq where id = p_id;
end;
/
```

Test in SQL*PLus

```
SQL> var n number
SQL> exec :n := 0;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec p(1, :n);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from tmp$;

        ID          L          R
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1         14
       600          2         13
       690          3         12
      6900          4          9
     69300          5          6
     69400          7          8
      6990         10         11

7 rows selected.
```

Comment: Typo Corrected!

Comment: Where would my `WITH tab1 as (...)` statement go?

Comment: Could you provide a version of the procedure that returns collections?

Comment: I used `create table tab1 as (...)`.

Comment: If you want to get result as a collection then use in/out collection parameter and make minor changes to the source code. You may also need to create a type for collection of records with 3 fields `(p_id in int, seq in out int)`.

Comment: Is there any way you could provide that version as well? I've never worked with collections before and would like to learn how it should be used. Thanks!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a *code writing service*. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348591/how-to-flag-close-as-not-a-code-writing-service. If you struggle converting my procedure to use collections instead of temporary table then create new topic and show what you tried to do.